# Why use 'has' when the word before it is plural noun?

Tags: grammar, tenses, sentence, verb-agreement, irregular-plurals

I have an English book, in which there is a sentence that confuses me.

The sentence is

> In the past years, the business of clothes has grown well.

I'm confused because why the author use the word 'has' for plural noun 'clothes'?

Comment: Because the verb is agreeing with "business" and not "clothes"

Comment: The OP's is a mistake a lot of people make. The verb should agree with the subject of the clause, not the last noun that appears before the verb.

Comment: @user888379 thank you!

Comment: @Robusto thank you! Btw, what's 'OP's' is?

Comment: OP is you. "Original Poster" ...

Comment: @alwayslearns Happy to help